# mPDF output not renaming downloadable file

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using the mpdf library, however I thought it would be rather simple to change the name of the download file when I download it, the documentation states the following:

```
<?php
Example #2
// Saves file on the server as 'filename.pdf'
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>Hallo World</p>');
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf','F');
?>
```

D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by filename.
http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=125&searchstring=download%20name

My code:

```
if(empty($_GET['module_id'])){
        echo 'Please select a module on the previous page.';
    }else{
        global $link;
        $moduleid = $_GET['module_id'];
        $assignment_id = $_GET['assignment_id'];
        $name = 'name';
        $code = 'code';
        $course_title = 'course_title';
        $title = 'title';
        $datedue = 'handin';
        $assignment_number = 'number';
        $weight = 'weighting';
        $handin = 'handin';
        $handout = 'handout';
        $feedback = 'feedback';
        $brief = 'brief';
        $submission_procedure = 'sub_details';
        $additional_notes = 'add_note';


$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `code` FROM `module` WHERE `module_id` = '$moduleid'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    echo $row[0];
}
$file_name = $row[0];

ob_end_clean();



$mpdf = new mPDF('en-GB','A4','','',20,15,10,25,10,10);
$courseworkReceipt = '
<html>
<head>
     //HTML output removed
</body>
</html>
';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($courseworkReceipt);

$mpdf->AddPage();
$assignment = '
<html>
<head>
    /More HTML output removed
</body>
</html>
';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($assignment);
$mpdf->Output($file_name, 'D');    //<-- problem
exit;
}
```

Whenever the file downloads it downloads as 'download.pdf' rather than my variable $file_name.

Comment: If you echo $file_name; just before your ->Output call, is there a value?

Comment: Yes. The value is "COM3371", what I expected it to be.

Comment: @IarsAnders I needed it for the HTML to be converted to PDF using the library. 

http://processwire.com/talk/topic/4338-how-to-include-mpdf/

Comment: Interesting, I did not need to use that for my installation of mPDF.

Comment: Have you tried casting to string?  $file_name = (string)$file_name;

Comment: I thought this would be an easy task, I never knew re-naming a download file would be so difficult lol

Comment: Nope, still nothing even when I cast it as a string :(

Comment: Two more thoughts - 1) when you say that the variable has a value, is that because the echo inside the while loop shows a value, or is it because you added a second echo statement just before the Output command? 2) Try changing the variable to just $filename. They use that variable name in the mPDF docs.

Comment: I made a function in another PHP file to do the rename, and it works. lol.

Comment: It must be related to the ob_end_clean(); since the function works.

Comment: Odd, have you tried the original code without it?

Comment: It just names the document 'pdf-downlaod.pdf'

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `"I"` parameter:

```
$mpdf->Output("My downloadable pdf.pdf", "I");
```

`I`: send the file inline to the browser (http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=125&searchstring=download%20name)

Tested & working with the latest version of mPDF.

Answer (score 1):

Hop :

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML($assignment);
$mpdf->Output($file_name, 'D');  
rename('download.pdf', $file_name);
exit;
```

Comment: Sadly didn't fix the problem, however the download filename has now changed between 'pdf.pdf' and 'pdf-download.pdf'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you should have to do this with mpdf, but adding a content disposition header before the `$mpdf->output()` call might help:

`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');`

Setting the content-disposition set what your browser should save the file as.